# How can i check and retrieve empty double value using Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I am working with flutter desktop project, i want to retrieve some double values but when proceed some field as an empty field and try to retrieve the data and i got an error to fill up all the TextField i have. How can i check those TextField as an empty field and retrieve an empty value.

> Error:- ════════ Exception caught by gesture
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture: Invalid double
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
> #0      double.parse (dart:core-patch/double_patch.dart:111:28)
> #1      _HomePageState.build.. package:urban_laundry/page/home_page.dart:992
> #2      State.setState package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1088
> #3      _HomePageState.build. package:urban_laundry/page/home_page.dart:975
> #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:989
> #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:193
> #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:608
> #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:296
> #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:230
> #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:558
> #10     PointerRouter._dispatch package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94
> #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes. package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139
> #12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:400:8)
> #13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137
> #14     PointerRouter.route package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123
> #15     GestureBinding.handleEvent package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:440
> #16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:420
> #17     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:278

Code :-

```
  final price1 = TextEditingController();
  final price2 = TextEditingController();
  final price3 = TextEditingController();

  final deliveryCharge = TextEditingController();

  double? p1;
  double? p2;
  double? p3;
  double? delivery;
  double total = 0.0;

  void priceTotal() {
    double p1 = double.parse(price1.text);
    double p2 = double.parse(price2.text);
    double p3 = double.parse(price3.text);

    double delivery = double.parse(deliveryCharge.text);

    print(total.toString());
    setState(() {
      total = (p1 + p2 + p3 + delivery);
    });
  }
```

TextField :-

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
      top: 10.0, left: 10.0),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 200.0,
    child: TextField(
      controller: price3,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10.0)),
        ),
        prefixIcon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: FaIcon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.rupeeSign,
            size: 20.0,
          ),
        ),
        hintText: 'Price',
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

OnPress :-

```
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      delivery = double.parse(deliveryCharge.text);
      p1 = double.parse(price1.text);
      p2 = double.parse(price2.text);
      p3 = double.parse(price3.text);
      priceTotal();
    });
  },
```

[image: Image Here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is null, you can replace it with zero. Let's try.

```
      delivery = double.parse(deliveryCharge.text??"0");
      p1 = double.parse(price1.text??"0");
      p2 = double.parse(price2.text??"0");
      p3 = double.parse(price3.text??"0");
```

Comment: lib/page/home_page.dart:990:71: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'TextEditingController' which excludes null.
 - 'TextEditingController' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart').
                                              delivery = double.parse(deliveryCharge?.text??"0");

Comment: you can replace `?.` with just dot(.) and also updated my answer

Comment: Thankyou for your response

Comment: lib/page/home_page.dart:994:58: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                                                  price3.text ?? "0");
                                                         ^

Comment: otherwise you can try `double.parse(price3.text!=null && price3.text.isNotEmpty?price3.text:"0")`

Comment: Yes this work, but can we enter empty string instead of "0"

Comment: Thank you so much. How can i make as empty " "

Comment: don't replace zero, double parse can't convert the empty string